# Pascal VOC annotations not working in CVAT.ai

Tags: xml, neural-network, object-detection, cvat

I've used [cvat.ai](https://cvat.ai) online tool to create annotations for over 100 images. I wanted to use them later in object detection with ***Pascal VOC 1.1*** format. Unfortunately, after exporting the annotations, the xml files corresponding to each of the images do not have any of my annotations included.

Example for file **1.png**.

Annotations in cvat.ai for 1.png file : [image]

The content of the **1.xml** file:

```
<annotation>
  <folder></folder>
  <filename>1.png</filename>
  <source>
    <database>Unknown</database>
    <annotation>Unknown</annotation>
    <image>Unknown</image>
  </source>
  <size>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>400</height>
    <depth></depth>
  </size>
  <segmented>1</segmented>
</annotation>
```

I've also tried exporting in different format. It turned out, that in ***CVAT for images 1.1*** format my annotations are included. All of them are stored in single XML file **annotations.xml**. Here is the part of this file with annotations from 1.png:

```
 <image id="0" name="1.png" width="400" height="400">
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="319.28" cy="25.56" rx="6.63" ry="6.90" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="372.07" cy="100.76" rx="3.98" ry="3.85" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="340.24" cy="55.54" rx="17.24" ry="15.12" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="341.43" cy="64.95" rx="6.76" ry="6.76" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="111.97" cy="319.61" rx="8.89" ry="7.83" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="251.90" cy="79.01" rx="4.77" ry="5.17" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="270.07" cy="93.07" rx="4.91" ry="5.70" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="315.70" cy="193.21" rx="3.85" ry="3.71" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="297.00" cy="151.96" rx="7.43" ry="5.70" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="240.23" cy="179.41" rx="6.10" ry="6.63" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="260.26" cy="164.83" rx="7.03" ry="6.10" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="335.46" cy="279.95" rx="4.77" ry="4.51" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="362.52" cy="58.98" rx="4.51" ry="4.51" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="291.83" cy="0.18" rx="9.95" ry="8.77" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="306.81" cy="314.30" rx="14.32" ry="12.87" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="274.85" cy="243.48" rx="27.99" ry="25.86" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="181.21" cy="244.94" rx="4.38" ry="4.24" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="155.74" cy="40.02" rx="5.44" ry="5.17" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="51.89" cy="95.59" rx="4.51" ry="3.98" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="60.38" cy="95.86" rx="4.24" ry="3.71" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="182.27" cy="133.92" rx="5.70" ry="5.44" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="233.23" cy="381.10" rx="4.60" ry="4.24" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="186.35" cy="362.68" rx="4.15" ry="3.68" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="308.76" cy="383.04" rx="2.95" ry="3.04" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="317.97" cy="396.39" rx="3.32" ry="3.13" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="189.85" cy="47.21" rx="4.14" ry="3.61" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse label="Crater" source="manual" occluded="0" cx="192.35" cy="259.31" rx="24.64" ry="24.81" z_order="0">
    </ellipse>
  </image>
```

How can I include those annotations in Pascal VOC? Is this because my annotations are ellipses, not squares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the reason is the shape of the annotations. After changing them from ellipses to squares in my project at cvat.ai, Pascal VOC xml files have information about annotations and their positions.